# GLL Parser Combinator or Generator in/for C or C++

Tags: c++, c, parsing, parser-combinators, parse-forest

Is there any existing implementation of the [GLL](http://dotat.at/tmp/gll.pdf) algorithm, either in the form of parser combinators (preferred) or as a parser generator for C or C++?

My requirements are that the output is a shared packed parse forest (SPPF) which I can later disambiguate using semantic and/or contextual rules. There are other parsing algorithms such as GLR which are able to cope with general context-free grammars, however, all GLR parser generators I could find either return the first successful parse tree or fail if any ambiguity remains at the end.

Comment: I understand Bison has a GLR switch, but I don't know what its properties are.   I'm suprised that those tools you could find objected if there were any remaining ambiguities (we use GLR parsers and *keep* these precisely to do semantic analysis as you suggest).  If they do, there must be a moment in time in which they have the entire tree ambiguities and all; you should be able to step in an take the tree at that moment.

Comment: According to the [Bison homepage](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Generalized-LR-Parsing.html), its GLR parser is exponential in time (i.e. it isn't implemented correctly, as a GLR parser with the correct data structures is O(n³)

Comment: Have you considered an Earley parser as an alternative to a GLL parser? [Marpa](https://metacpan.org/pod/Marpa::R2) is an Earley parser for Perl that is implemented via a C library.

Comment: Have you seen http://sourceforge.net/projects/cocom/ (docs at http://cocom.sourceforge.net/ammunition++-13.html )

Comment: Have you checked https://github.com/djspiewak/gll-combinators ?

Comment: @EvgeniyZh Scala is not c++

Answer (score 0):

What if you try out [*GLL Combinators*](https://github.com/djspiewak/gll-combinators)? Although it uses Scala, you may write "thin" wrappers for it by means of the [JNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface).

> **GLL Combinators** is a framework designed to implement the [GLL parsing algorithm](http://ldta.info/2009/ldta2009proceedings.pdf)
>   (Scott and Johnstone, LDTA 2009) in a functional manner.  More specifically, the
>   framework makes use of atomic parser combinators to compose grammars which are
>   then evaluated using the GLL algorithm.  The framework provides a syntax for this
>   task which is almost identical to that of the parser combinator framework built
>   into Scala.  For example, we can render the classic "parentheses grammar" using
>   GLL combinators:
>
> ```
> lazy val expr: Parser[Any] = (
>     "(" ~ expr ~ ")"
>   | ""
> )
> ```
>
> As the type annotation implies, `expr` will reference an instance of type
>   `Parser[Any]`.  That is, an atomic parser which consumes some input and returns
>   a value of type `Any`.  We can invoke this parser against a `String` input
>   in the following way:
>
> ```
> expr("((()))")
> ```
>
> This will return a value of type `Stream[Result[Any]]`.  The `Result[A]` ADT is
>   defined as one of the following (for some type `A`):
>
> - `Success[A]` -- Represents a successful parse and contains the resulting value.
> - `Failure` -- Represents a failed parse and contains the relevant error message
>     as well as the remainder of the parse stream (the characters which were not
>     consumed).
>
> If any result is successful (i.e. an instance of `Success[A]`), then no failures
>   will be returned.  Thus, the `Stream` returned will be completely homogeneous,
>   containing *either* `Success` or `Failure`, but not both.  A `Stream` is
>   returned rather than a single value to allow for ambiguity in the grammar (see
>   below).
>
> It's worth mentioning that GLL is a form of [recursive-descent parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser).  It has
>   all of the advantages of conventional recursive-descent, including an intuitive
>   control flow, arbitrary positioning of semantic actions and superior error
>   messages.  In fact, it is the fact that GLL is recursive-descent which allows it
>   to be implemented using atomic combinators.  Other algorithms which share the
>   same capabilities as GLL (such as GLR, Earley Parsing, etc) are fundamentally
>   incompatible with the combinator model due to their highly-unintuitive control
>   flow.  In GLL parsing, the control flow follows that of the grammar, as it does
>   in traditional parser combinators or any other form of recursive-descent.

Comment: I very much doubt there is *any* reasonable mapping for the combinators themselves via JNI.

Comment: @Joe: Not for the combinators themselves, no. That's simply non-sense. I was thinking that you could create some kind of wrapper *in Scheme* that makes the calls easier for C/C++ code,. and call those functions throught JNI